# .htaccess redirect certain files

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I don`t know anything about .htaccess files except how to secure a folder or deny access.

I want to deny direct access to `.js` files (by typing the file name in url) on my server, say the files are stored in a folder named `/js/` how can I use the .htaccess to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that.

Actually there is no 'direct access' or 'indirect access'. The browser accesses the JS file the same way when you load it from a SCRIPT tag and when you try to load it separately (typing the file name in browser).